# How to get Public IP Subnet and default gateway value on my Debian Linux?

Tags: ip, routing, vpn, nordvpn

In order to configure my VPN, I need to determine these values:

Public IP  : I can do that with **curl ifconfig.me**

Public IP Subnet : **How do get this value ?**

Default Gateway : **how to get this value ?**
I tried with **route**

eth0 is device to gateway : : how to get this value ?
I tried with **route**

Comment: This does not look like [the normal procedure to set up NordVPN](https://support.nordvpn.com/Connectivity/Linux/1325531132/Installing-and-using-NordVPN-on-Debian-Ubuntu-Raspberry-Pi-Elementary-OS-and-Linux-Mint.htm) (NordVPN is mentioned in the tags). Just what VPN client are you using?

Comment: nordvpn whitelist add subnet 192.168.0.0/16
How do I get this address on a remote linux server ?

Comment: You arrange a meeting with someone who understands the remote network, to figure out which systems the server will need to access locally while the VPN is active, and calculate the appropriate set of whitelist entries that exactly includes what the server needs and (ideally) nothing more. **This is not something you can blindly copy and paste without understanding the network the server is in.** If the server has firewall rules configured, you might use them as clues as to what you'll need to whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

Subnets do not usually make sense for remote (public) networks. You can find out the network size given to the respective AS but that is not the same like a subnet.

Assuming the (i.e. a single) default gateway has already been configured you can get it with this:

```
ip route list default | awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i=="via") print $(i+1); }'
```

You can find the device for reaching the default gateway by using the former commands output in this command:

```
ip route get 192.168.213.1 | awk '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i=="dev") { print $(i+1); exit;} }'
```

Comment: This is what I found : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/365285/how-to-allow-ssh-into-terminal-after-connecting-to-vpn-server-using-nordvpn-serv

Comment: Apologies for the tiny edit. I connect to an IPsec VPN that does have a public subnet. There is a firewall but no NAT so all IPs at the remote subnet are public.  Though I'm not convinced it's technically relevant to this question and it's reasonably obscure.

Comment: @PhilipCouling And what is the effect of that subnet?

Comment: @Haukelaging in those VPNs it limits the public range associated with the VPN so clients understand what to route through it and what not to.